# Do a keyword search on loggly

Tags: json, heroku, loggly

Anyone know how to search by keyword through loggly JSON logs?

I have JSON logs with a key `messageText` and if I search for `cat` i want a log with `messageText: "someone took a photo of their cat"` which should return about a bajillion results, but instead it returns 0.

I have tried:

```
search json.messageText:cat
search json.messageText:%cat%
```

but I'm just gessing at this point. Loggly's help is unhelpful. It's entirely possible that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
search json.messageText:"*cat*"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just spent an hour stuck on this one, too. Their "filter system" shows that they do a search on "json.key1.key2 : value8".

BUT, if you want to do the exact same search, you have to type in "key1.key2 : value8", which is essentially the same thing without the "json." at the beginning. The interface is very misleading and confusing about this.

So basically, don't put the "json." and the beginning of searches.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to type "search" at the beginning.

First, you can do a text-based search, on all fields, by just typing:

```
cat
```

Now, if you want to restrict your search to the field json.MessageText:

```
json.messageText:cat
```